# Maximal region in the cylindrical space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

I would like to determine a maximal region in $(r, \theta, z)$- space which maps injectively into $(x,y,z)$-space

Thank you

Comment: Interesting. Wish I could help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Don't bound $z$. Bound $r$ below by $0$ (should this be strict, or non-strict?), and don't bound it above. Bound $\theta$ appropriately. (There are infinitely many ways to do this.)

**Note**: I am assuming, here, that "region" means "open connected set". If that isn't what you intend, let me know. I further assume that you mean for the change-of-coordinate map to be injective. If you just need *a* map, we could let $x=r,y=\theta,z=z$, and map the entire space injectively.

Comment: Could you provide more details ? I am actually interested myself in this proof

Comment: The change-of-coordinate map is given by $$(r,\theta,z)\mapsto(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z).$$ The third coordinate will provide no problems for injectivity, so we don't want to bound $z$. The bound on $r$ allows for injectivity, once we've chosen appropriate bounds for $\theta$ to account for the periodic nature of the trig functions. Not bounding $r$ above makes maximality possible, and appropriate $\theta$ bounds will ensure it.

Comment: @CameronBuie I have a question: If I assume that $r \cos \theta = r \cos \theta'$ how can I show that $\theta = \theta '$ ?

Comment: @CameronBuie Good question. How can you show that? Using the periodicity ?

Comment: @Carpediem: In general, you can't. For example, if you allow $r=0$, then we can't say anything at all about how $\theta,\theta'$ may be related. Even if $r\ne0$, so that $\cos\theta=\cos\theta'$, we still can't necessarily conclude that $\theta=\theta'$. However, if we happen to know that $\cos\theta=\cos\theta'$ **and** that $\sin\theta=\sin\theta'$, then we can conclude that $\theta'=\theta+2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Does that give you an idea as to how big we can allow our $\theta$-interval to be?

Comment: @user43418: See my comment above.